# How to change Start time and End time in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have created small time calculation application, I need once select start time 10:00:00 then click add anther row next field start time 11:00:00, how do i change my code could you please check and update my code and also attached image need same ou.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TimeInputRow = ({ data, onFieldChange, onAddRow }) => {
  const { date, startTime, endTime, name, address } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="date" value={date} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('date', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={startTime} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('startTime', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={endTime} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('endTime', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('name', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Address" value={address} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('address', e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={onAddRow}>Add Row</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Apdemo = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    { date: '2023-01-01', startTime: '00:00:00', endTime: '00:00:00', name: 'John Doe', address: '123 Main St' }
  ]);

  console.log(rows)

  const handleFieldChange = (index, field, value) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setRows(newRows);
  };

  const handleAddRow = async () => {
    const lastIndex = rows.length - 1;
    const lastRow = rows[lastIndex];
    const rowsInput={
      date:rows[0].date,
      startTime:rows[0].startTime+parseInt('10:00:00'),
      endTime:rows[0].endTime,
      name:rows[0].name,
      address:rows[0].address 
  } 
  setRows([...rows, rowsInput])

  };

  const addOneDay = (date) => {
    const currentDate = new Date(date);
    const nextDay = new Date(currentDate);
    nextDay.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  };
console.log(rows)
  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((data, index) => (
        <TimeInputRow
          key={index}
          data={data}
          onFieldChange={(field, value) => handleFieldChange(index, field, value)}
          onAddRow={handleAddRow}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Apdemo;
```

update output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brQqR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this? If not, please clarify your question for me. I have just updated your handleAddRow function to always add one hour (you can modify it by changing the +2 from the following line: `lastEndTime.setHours(lastEndTime.getHours() + 2);`). The entire code looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TimeInputRow = ({ data, onFieldChange, onAddRow }) => {
  const { date, startTime, endTime, name, address } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="date"
        value={date}
        onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('date', e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"
        value={startTime}
        onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('startTime', e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"
        value={endTime}
        onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('endTime', e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('name', e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Address"
        value={address}
        onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('address', e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={onAddRow}>Add Row</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Apdemo = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {
      date: '2023-01-01',
      startTime: '00:00:00',
      endTime: '00:00:00',
      name: 'John Doe',
      address: '123 Main St',
    },
  ]);

  const handleFieldChange = (index, field, value) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setRows(newRows);
  };

  const handleAddRow = async () => {
    const lastIndex = rows.length - 1;
    const lastRow = rows[lastIndex];

    // Parse the end time of the last row
    const lastEndTime = new Date(`2023-01-01 ${lastRow.endTime}`);

    // Add 10 hours to the end time
    lastEndTime.setHours(lastEndTime.getHours() + 2);

    const rowsInput = {
      date: addOneDay(lastRow.date),
      startTime: formatTime(lastEndTime),
      endTime: formatTime(lastEndTime),
      name: 'John Doe',
      address: '123 Main St',
    };

    setRows([...rows, rowsInput]);
  };

  const addOneDay = (date) => {
    const currentDate = new Date(date);
    const nextDay = new Date(currentDate);
    nextDay.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  };

  const formatTime = (time) => {
    return time.toISOString().split('T')[1].slice(0, 8);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((data, index) => (
        <TimeInputRow
          key={index}
          data={data}
          onFieldChange={(field, value) =>
            handleFieldChange(index, field, value)
          }
          onAddRow={handleAddRow}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Apdemo;
```

Comment: thanks Pascal Can you please give example Datepicker?

Comment: I didn't changed the Datepicker Component. I just added the addOnDay() Function and called it, everytime you create a new row

Comment: could you please let me know this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77701786/how-to-change-next-date-in-react

Answer (score 0):

"The handleAddRow function calculates the next start time based on the previous row's end time, and the end time of the new row is set to one hour after the start time."

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TimeInputRow = ({ data, onFieldChange, onAddRow }) => {
  const { date, startTime, endTime, name, address } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="date" value={date} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('date', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={startTime} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('startTime', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" value={endTime} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('endTime', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('name', e.target.value)} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Address" value={address} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('address', e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={onAddRow}>Add Row</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Apdemo = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    { date: '2023-01-01', startTime: '10:00:00', endTime: '11:00:00', name: 'John Doe', address: '123 Main St' }
  ]);

  const handleFieldChange = (index, field, value) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setRows(newRows);
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const lastIndex = rows.length - 1;
    const lastRow = rows[lastIndex];
    const nextRow = {
      date: lastRow.date,
      startTime: lastRow.endTime, 
      endTime: addOneHour(lastRow.endTime),
      name: '',
      address: ''
    };

    setRows([...rows, nextRow]);
  };

  const addOneHour = (time) => {
    const currentTime = new Date(`2000-01-01T${time}`);
    currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours() + 1);
    return currentTime.toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((data, index) => (
        <TimeInputRow
          key={index}
          data={data}
          onFieldChange={(field, value) => handleFieldChange(index, field, value)}
          onAddRow={handleAddRow}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Apdemo;
```

Comment: Hi  Akeel thanks for update, I need if i change endTime automatically comes start time please see above image. thanks

Comment: I have updated the code, you can try it.

Comment: Hi Akeel i have another question please this line  <input type="date" value={date} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('date', e.target.value)} /> to React Datepicker.