# How to change next date in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have created simple react application. I want to click button `<button onClick={onAddRow} className='add-row'><FaRegPlusSquare /></button>` change next date. I stored date  `const existing_date=formats; eg:2023-12-03` then need 2023-12-04 after click 2023-12-05, can you please update my code.
my code:

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AES, enc } from "crypto-js";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Header from '../Header'
import Footer from '../Footer'
import { FaRegTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { FaRegPlusSquare } from "react-icons/fa";

import axios from "axios";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Card,
  Col,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Row,
  Tooltip,
  Table,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { decryptedAccessToken, encryptedAccessToken } from "../../Token";
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";
import { parse, format } from 'date-fns';


const Laytime = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDaterow, setSelectedDaterow] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDaterow1, setSelectedDaterow1] = useState(null);

  const [formats, setDateformat]=useState([])
  const TimeInputRow = ({ data, onFieldChange, onAddRow }) => {
    const {time_start, time_end, percent_to_count, days_addtion } = data;
    const existing_date=formats;
    console.log(existing_date)
    // Format date as "day-month-year"
    // const formattedDate = new Date(existing_date).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
    // console.log(formattedDate)
  
  
    return (
      <div className='d-f'>
        {/* Use formattedDate instead of date */}
        <input type="text" defaultValue={existing_date } onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('existing_date', e.target.value)} />
        
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" defaultValue={time_start} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('time_start', e.target.value)} />
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" defaultValue={time_end} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('time_end', e.target.value)} />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Percent Count" defaultValue={percent_to_count} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('percent_to_count',parseInt( e.target.value))} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Days Addtion" defaultValue={days_addtion} onChange={(e) => onFieldChange('days_addtion', e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={onAddRow} className='add-row'><FaRegPlusSquare /></button>
      </div>
    );
  };
    
  
  

  const location=useLocation();
  const {id}=location.state;
  console.log(id)
  const [laytime, setLaytime]=useState([])
  const [exist, setExist]=useState([])
  useEffect(() => {

    fetchData5();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData5 = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/get/laytime_byID/'+id, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },        }
      );
      const data = response.data.laytime[0];
      const data1 = response.data.existing_laytime;
      const rowDate = response.data.laytime[0].time_to_count_for;
      
      setLaytime(data)
      setExist(data1)
      const dateRegex = /^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/;
      const dateMatch = rowDate.match(dateRegex);
      const datePart = dateMatch ? dateMatch[1] : null; // '01-12-2023'
      console.log(datePart)
      const defaultDatepicker = parse(datePart, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());
              const formattedDatepicker = format(defaultDatepicker, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
              setDateformat(formattedDatepicker)
            
      setSelectedDaterow1(defaultDatepicker);
      console.log(datePart)


} catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
   

console.log()
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); 
  const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [editedData, setEditedData] = useState([]);
  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditMode(true);
    setEditedData(data);
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setLaytime((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

 const handleCancelEdit = () => {
    setIsEditMode(false);
    setEditedData(data);
     
  };



  const handleChangeExist = (index, field, value) => {
    const newRows = [...exist];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setExist(newRows);


  };


  const handleExist=()=>{
 //  "/update/existing_laytime/<laytime_id>"          update_existing_laytime
 const responseUpdate={
  "records":exist


}

 console.log(JSON.stringify(responseUpdate))
 fetch(`https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/update/existing_laytime/${id}`, {
   method: 'PUT',
   body: JSON.stringify(responseUpdate),
   headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

 })
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((updatedData) => {
     console.log(updatedData)
     window.location.reload();

   })
   .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};

// time to count
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
// const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState('');

const handleDateChange = (date) => {
  setSelectedDate(date);
 };

 const [selectedDate1, setSelectedDate1] = useState(new Date());
// const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState('');

const handleDateChange1 = (date) => {
  setSelectedDate1(date);
 };
 const [selectedDate2, setSelectedDate2] = useState(new Date());
// const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState('');
const [formattedDateApend, setFormattedDateApend] = useState('');

const handleDateChange2 = (date) => {
  setSelectedDate2(date);

 


const formatted = date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: '2-digit',
  year: 'numeric',

}).replace(/\//g, '-');

setFormattedDateApend(formatted);


};
 const [selectedDate3, setSelectedDate3] = useState(new Date());
// const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState('');

const handleDateChange3 = (date) => {
  setSelectedDate3(date);
 };

  const [originalDateString, setOriginalDateString] = useState('2023-12-11 14:30:00');
  const originalDateObject = new Date(originalDateString);
  const isoString = originalDateObject.toISOString();
  console.log(isoString)
  const handleSaveEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const responseUpdate={
      "vessel_name":laytime.vessel_name,
      "orderID":laytime.orderID,
      "loading_at":laytime.loading_at,
      "buyer_name":laytime.buyer_name,
      "cargo":laytime.cargo,
      "seller":laytime.seller,
      "bl_quantity":laytime.bl_quantity,
      "shipper":laytime.shipper,
      "contract_number":laytime.contract_number,
      "days_allowed":laytime.days_allowed,
      "lp_agent":laytime.lp_agent,
      "sailing_date":laytime.sailing_date,
      "loading_rate":laytime.loading_rate,
      "NOR_tendered":laytime.NOR_tendered,
      "notice_of_readiness":laytime.notice_of_readiness,
      "NOR_accepted":selectedDate,
      "commenced_load":selectedDate1,
      "laycan":laytime.laycan,
      "time_to_count_for":selectedDate2,
      "demurrage":laytime.demurrage,
      "completed_load":selectedDate3,
      "despatch":laytime.despatch


    }
  //  "/update/existing_laytime/<laytime_id>"          update_existing_laytime
    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseUpdate))
    fetch(`https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/update/laytime/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(responseUpdate),
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((updatedData) => {
        console.log(updatedData)
        window.location.reload();
        toast.success('Laytime Updated Successfully', {
          position: "bottom-center",
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "light",
          });

      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };




  // add row


  const localStorageKey = 'timeInputRows';

  // Load rows from local storage or use default value
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(() => {
    const storedRows = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);
    return storedRows ? JSON.parse(storedRows) : [
      { existing_date: '', time_start: '00:00:00', time_end: '24:00:00', percent_to_count: '', days_addtion: '' }
    ];
  });

  // Save rows to local storage whenever it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(rows));
  }, [rows]);

  const handleFieldChange = (index, field, value) => {
    const newRows = [...rows];
    newRows[index][field] = value;
    setRows(newRows);
  };

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    const lastIndex = rows.length - 1;
    const lastRow = rows[lastIndex];

    // Check if the last row is empty before adding a new row
    if (Object.values(lastRow).some(value => value === '')) {
      alert('Please fill in all fields before adding a new row.');
      return;
    }

    const nextDate = addOneDay(lastRow.existing_date);
    const nextStartTime = lastRow.time_end === '24:00:00' ? '00:00:00' : lastRow.time_end;
    const nextEndTime = '00:00:00';

    
    setRows(prevRows => [
      ...prevRows,
      { existing_date: nextDate, time_start: nextStartTime, time_end: nextEndTime, percent_to_count: '', days_addtion: '' },
    ]);
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = (index) => {
    if (rows.length > 1) {
      const newRows = [...rows];
      newRows.splice(index, 1);
      setRows(newRows);
    } else {
      // If there's only one row, clear its values instead of removing it
      setRows([{ existing_date: '', time_start: '', time_end: '', percent_to_count: '', days_addtion: '' }]);
    }
  };
  const addOneDay = (date) => {
    const currentDate = new Date(date);
    const nextDay = new Date(currentDate);
    nextDay.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
  };


  const handleSubmit=()=>{
  console.log(formats)
  
    const responseUpdate={
      "existing_laytime": rows


    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(responseUpdate))

    fetch(`https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/add/existing_laytime/${id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(responseUpdate),
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((updatedData) => {
        console.log(updatedData)
        // window.location.reload();
        toast.success('Add Existing Laytime Successfully', {
          position: "bottom-center",
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "light",
          });

      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }


  return (
    <div>
    <div className="priceAccount" id='prices'>
    <Header/>
    <div>
    <div className="page-header" id=''>
    <div>
      <h2 className="main-content-title tx-24 mg-b-5">LayTime Detailes</h2>
      <ol className="breadcrumb">
        <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard / LayTime Detailes</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
{/* <button onClick={handlesubmit}>ddsdsd</button> */}

  </div>
     </div>
     <div className='tasks'>

      {isEditMode ? (
        <>
          

        <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSaveEdit}>Save</button></>
      ):(
        <>
         <div className="edit-delete">
                  <span id="edit" onClick={handleEditClick}>
                    Edit
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    Delete
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    Clone
                  </span>
                  </div>
                  <h4 className='heading m-t'>Order Information</h4>
     <table class="table table-bordered account-table tables">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>orderID</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.orderID}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>vessel name</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.vessel_name}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>loading at</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.loading_at}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>buyer name</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.buyer_name}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>cargo</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.cargo}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>seller</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.seller}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>bl_quantity</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.bl_quantity}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>shipper</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.shipper}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>contract number</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.contract_number}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>days allowed</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.days_allowed}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>lp agent</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.lp_agent}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>sailing date</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.sailing_date}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>loading rate</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.loading_rate}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>NOR tendered</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.NOR_tendered}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>notice of readiness</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.notice_of_readiness}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>NOR accepted</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.NOR_accepted}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>turn time</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.turn_time}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>commenced load</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.commenced_load}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>laycan</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.laycan}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>time to count for</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.time_to_count_for}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>demurrage</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.demurrage}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span>completed load</span></td>
        <td>{laytime.completed_load}
        </td>
        
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td id="td-right"><span>despatch</span> </td>
        <td>{laytime.despatch}</td>
        <td id="td-right"><span></span></td>
        <td></td>
        
      </tr> 
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </>
      )}




  

        <h4 className='heading m-t'> Exist Laytime</h4>
        <table className='table'>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Existing Date</th>
    <th>Time Start</th>
    <th>Time End</th>
    <th>Percent To Count</th>
    <th>Stoppage Remarks</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {exist.map((x, i)=>(
    <tr key={i}>
    <td>
      
      <input type='text' defaultValue={x.existing_date} name='existing_date' onChange={(field, value) => handleChangeExist(field, value)}/>
    </td>
     <td >
     <input type='text' defaultValue={x.time_start} name='time_start' onChange={(field, value) => handleChangeExist( field, value)}/>
   </td>
   <td >
     <input type='text' defaultValue={x.time_end} name='time_end' onChange={(field, value) => handleChangeExist(field, value)}/>
   </td>
   <td >
     <input type='text' defaultValue={x.percent_to_count} name='time_end' onChange={(field, value) => handleChangeExist(field, value)}/>
   </td>
   <td >
     <input type='text' defaultValue={x.stoppage_remarks} name='stoppage_remarks' onChange={(field, value) => handleChangeExist(field, value)}/>
   </td>
   </tr>
  ))}
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleExist}>Save</button>

<h4 className='heading m-t'> Add New Laytime</h4>
 
        {rows.map((data, index) => (
          <div key={index} className='d-f'>
            <TimeInputRow
              data={data}
              onFieldChange={(field, value) => handleFieldChange(index, field, value)}
              onAddRow={handleAddRow}
            />
            <button className='remove-row' onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(index)}><FaRegTrashAlt /></button>
          </div>
        ))}
      <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>

    
        </div>

</div>
        <ToastContainer/>
    <Footer/>
     </div>
  );
};

export default Laytime;
```

Comment: could you please help me genius

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your handleAddRow function to calculate the next date and time for the new row.
In this code, the addOneDay function takes a date as input and returns the next day's date. The handleAddRow function then uses this function to calculate the next date for the new row.
Try this code:-

```
const handleAddRow = () => {
  const lastIndex = rows.length - 1;
  const lastRow = rows[lastIndex];

  // Check if the last row is empty before adding a new row
  if (Object.values(lastRow).some(value => value === '')) {
    alert('Please fill in all fields before adding a new row.');
    return;
  }

  const nextDate = addOneDay(lastRow.existing_date);
  const nextStartTime = lastRow.time_end === '24:00:00' ? '00:00:00' : lastRow.time_end;
  const nextEndTime = '00:00:00';

  setRows(prevRows => [
    ...prevRows,
    { existing_date: nextDate, time_start: nextStartTime, time_end: nextEndTime, percent_to_count: '', days_addition: '' },
  ]);
};

const addOneDay = (date) => {
  const currentDate = new Date(date);
  const nextDay = new Date(currentDate);
  nextDay.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
  return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
};
```